# Template method within one class without subclasses or inheritance

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, delegates

I have an algorithm with mostly invariant parts that needs to be reused within one class so as to stay [DRY](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/short-introduction-to-solid-and-dry-for.html).

#### Code duplication with repeating method structure

```
public void save(String key, int value) {
    try {
        if (isValidWrite()) {
            // Only variable part
            editor.putInt(key, value);
            if (!writeOnDisable){
                write(editor);                    
                Log.v(TAG, "Saved " + key + " | "+ value);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "save", e);
    }
}

public void save(String key, String value) {
    try {
        if (isValidWrite()) {
            // Only variable part
            editor.putString(key, value);
            if (!writeOnDisable){
                write(editor);
                Log.v(TAG, "Saved " + key + " | "+ value);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "save", e);
    }
}
```

#### Solution?

- [The template method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) is not applicable, because it requires sub-classing.
- Strategy - do I really need to create an interface and provide different implementations to pass into a generalized method as a delegate? Maybe I'm just complaining about proper support for delegates in Java.. (in C# could just use a generic Action<>)

Comment: If you can't subclass your own class, maybe you can make the method generic and make `editor.put()` generic to match?

Comment: @KilianFoth that would work if I had access to editor source, but it happens to be part of Android framework.. And it would probably require a bunch of type-checking if statements, which impacts sense of elegance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void applyParameters(Editor editor, Object [] parameters) {
    for(Object param : parameters) {
        if(param instanceof Integer) {  
            editor.putInt(key, param);
        } else if (param instanceof String) {
            editor.putString(key, param);
        } else {
            // case for unknown type?
        }
    }
}
public void save(String key, Object ... params) {
    try {
        if (isValidWrite()) {
            if(params != null) 
                applyParameters(editor, params);

            if (!writeOnDisable){
                write(editor);                    
                Log.v(TAG, "Saved " + key + " | "+ value);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "save", e);
    }
}
```

Try this.  Essentially, you cannot generalize "putInt" and "putString", but you can at least extrapolate them into their own method.  Just provide a case for parameters you do not recognize as valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is al alternate solution, you expose two methods, one for `ints` and one for `Strings`.

A private method receives both kind of values and decides what to save.

```
public void save(String key, int value) {
    save(key, new Integer(value), null); // pass null in String param
}


public void save(String key, String value ) {
    save(key, null, value); // pass null in Integer param
}

private void save(String key, Integer intVal, String strVal){
    String strToLog="";
    try {
        if (isValidWrite()) {
            if ( intVal != null) {
                editor.putInt(key, intVal);
                strToLog = intVal.toString();
            } else if ( strVal != null) {
                editor.putInt(key, strVal);
                strToLog = strVal;
            }               

            if (!writeOnDisable){
                write(editor);                    
                Log.v(TAG, "Saved " + key + " | "+ strToLog);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "save", e);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually have additional save methods with more types, which makes me prefer Neil's implementation.